# Getting the IPv4 Address from a request in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So im trying to create a whitelist for ip adresses in my api but when i do `request.socket.remoteAddress`
in express.js i get back a ipv6 address (i think) like this one:
`::ffff:127.0.0.1`
My question is how do i only get the address behind the `::ffff:`

Thanks in advance!

Tried using `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This will output the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1

```js
const net = require('net');

let address = '::ffff:127.0.0.1';

if (net.isIPv6(address)) {
    let ipv4Address = address.split('::ffff:')[1];
    console.log(ipv4Address); // Outputs: 127.0.0.1
}
```